# SQL Fiscal Year in report

Tags: sql

I have a sql query that shows the year in one column and the month in another. I can show the report as the current year but i need to show it in fiscal form, for example our fiscal yr is from oct-oct so how can I do this in sql?  My current query below:

```
SELECT TOP (15) dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalyear, 
                dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalmonth, 
                SUM(dbo.factqht_v2.baanstandarcost)                 AS stdcost, 
                CAST(dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalmonth AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + 
                CAST(dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalyear AS VARCHAR) AS CONCAT 
FROM   dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0 
       INNER JOIN dbo.factqht_v2 
         ON dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.epoch = dbo.factqht_v2.qhtwfclosedtimekey 
       INNER JOIN dbo.dimqht_v2 
         ON dbo.factqht_v2.qhtid = dbo.dimqht_v2.qhtid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.dimqhtmaterials_v2 
         ON dbo.factqht_v2.materialid = dbo.dimqhtmaterials_v2.materialid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.dimqhtdispositions_v2 
         ON dbo.factqht_v2.dispositionid = 
            dbo.dimqhtdispositions_v2.dispositionid 
GROUP  BY dbo.dimqhtdispositions_v2.TYPE, 
          dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalyear, 
          dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalmonth, 
          dbo.dimqht_v2.toplevelassembly_majoritemgroupdesc, 
          CAST(dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalmonth AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + 
          CAST(dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalyear AS VARCHAR) 
HAVING ( dbo.dimqhtdispositions_v2.TYPE = N'Scrap' ) 
       AND ( dbo.dimqht_v2.toplevelassembly_majoritemgroupdesc = 
             'Torquer Motors' ) 
ORDER  BY dbo.timelinedayres_v1_0.fiscalmonth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(month, 2 + DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Since we are in november, this will return 2012, if the date is october it will return 2011. You can adjust your offset.

If you're coming in from just a month/year then you could do something like this:

```
declare @month int
declare @year int
set @year = 2011
set @month = 10
    SELECT CASE  
               WHEN @month > 10  
                   THEN @year + 1
               ELSE 
                   @year
           END AS fiscalYear
```